# Domain Account migration

Tags: user-accounts

here follows the current scenario:

- Our farm is running MS SharePoint Server 2007 SP2.
- Our corporate, is migrating all accounts from DomainA to DomainB. For example, user DomainA\XXX will be migrated to DomainB\XXX.
- DomainA and DominB are with trusts between them.

I would like to know the possible consequences of this account migration (I think catastrophic) and whether there are tools or best practices able to support this use case.

About migration on users I only know that sid user history will be preserved. But I'm not sure that SharePoint will still recognize the correct user after migration has been performed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually quite catastrophic for SharePoint as all SIDs are used within SharePoint.
I've had the experience of migrating from A to B (all user names maintained the same) and all security (farm included) was messed up.

I would suggest rather keep the trust and if possible let the users in the previous domain and the trust between domains should do the rest.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: I had a consultant once tell me they did something similar this, but it required some custom scripting to make sure everything worked.

Comment: Most likely, but is not an easy job to update application data with new accounts. You could consider a script to take every single account in User Profile and update its property - SID most important (read-only by default!), but this won't 100% guarantee.